# Video courses on sound design for film/tv ?

Tags: design, dvd, video, course

Hi!! new member here..

I'm looking for dvd's or video courses on sound design for film/tv.
I would like to learn everything from recording the right way to adding audio effects or anything needed like eq's or mastering before being ready to use or sell.

All help will be much appreciated. : )

Comment:  I don't know about video courses, though there's plenty of inspirational material out there in e.g. Youtube. My suggestion, if you're really motivated, is to just force yourself to work a soundtrack over a video clip. If you know the very basics of how to record to a DAW and/or a portable recorder, how to import and edit audio and how to use plug-ins, or even how to write or at least edit music, then that's practically all you need to start with. The rest is practice / doing it again and again, listening and acquiring influences. 

Answer (score 2):

Look into the Avid webinars. They have a good number that are focused on post-production work. The ones w/ Scott Weber are particularly good, they just released a new one called Creating the Indie Film Soundtrack. It comes w/ a downloadable session, and it's all free (just requires registration).

Answer (score 0):

Good luck. The most i've found is "making of" featurettes, but as all making of featurettes, they're made for fans, not for creatives. They lack the whole process really. There are some good books such as Ric Viers Sound Effects Bible. Of course there is also no shortage of mixing tutorials, but far less for SFX. I'd love for someone to come on here and prove me wrong though!

Comment: Cool!! thanks. I've seen his website (Viers) and some of his videos. Will get the book today.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest picking up a copy of Audio Postproduction for Film and Video by Jay Rose; at the very least it's good to refer to.  It helped me out many times in the past and it gives you enough information to fully grasp what you are reading.  This book changed the way I approached audio projects while I was in school, and it still is within close reach on my desk.

Vimeo and YouTube are great sources to find "making-of" and "behind the scenes" clips.  However Rose's book will give you a good foundation on how to mix for a variety of media and  also provide some real insight into overall dynamic(s) processing.  Dave is right about the Sound Effects Bible.  This book is useful to almost anyone, and is particularly helpful if you  want to establish a set workflow in your recordings. There's always something new to learn.

(:

http://www.amazon.com/Audio-Postproduction-Second-After-Shoot/dp/0240809718

Comment: @Joel Oye, sabes que? Es la segunda vez que me recomiendan esos libros de Rose. Los reviews son muy buenos y parece que muchas escuelas los usan. Estoy esperando que me llegue el libro. Envié a buscarlo hace unos días.

Comment: @Oski Mi español es muy malo para que lo disculpen. Ese libro es muy bueno, estoy seguro de que le resultará útil. Mi versión tiene notas en todas partes y sido invaluable para mí. ¡Buena suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I think it's almost impossible to find anything. I've been searching for a while and the closest thing I've found was 30 minutes video tutorial for $25.00 plus s/h jaja..
Will have to get some books then.
thanks for your answers..

Answer (score 0):

Lynda.com has some music editing for film, not composition however. But, their videos are very well put together

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Lynda.com:

Audio for Film and Video with Pro Tools with Scott Hirsch
http://www.lynda.com/Pro-Tools-9-training/Audio-for-Film-and-Video-with/77862-2.html

Audio Post Workflow with Final Cut Pro X and Pro Tools with Scott Hirsch
http://www.lynda.com/Final-Cut-Pro-tutorials/Audio-Post-Workflow-Final-Cut-Pro-X-Pro-Tools/103055-2.html

Music Editing for TV and Film in Pro Tools with Skye Lewin
http://www.lynda.com/Pro-Tools-9-tutorials/Music-Editing-for-TV-and-Film-in-Pro-Tools/89611-2.html

I don't know whether they are any good, stumbled upon them a couple of days ago!

Answer (score 0):

I will check Lynda. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

SMPTE/AES Lecture on film sound for the music engineer
http://www.dplay.com/aes/film1.html
http://www.dplay.com/aes/film2.html

A 2 hour lecture by Jay Rose.