# Good Videos on SD/Mixing.

Tags: mixing, video

any good videos out there on sound design or mixing on a sound stage? i've seen most of the ones on you tube. are there any DVDs or anything like that?

jx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This previous post should get you started:

[Video courses on sound design for film/tv ?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/17767/video-courses-on-sound-design-for-film-tv)